# I have created a song player, I just want that it should play next song on completion

Tags: android, performance, optimization

I have tried a method to play next song on completion But it works fine But I think It's not the correct way so if you have any suggestion, how can I correct it please let me know please, please.

Java code

```
    public class Musicplay extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button play,next,previous;
    TextView song mar;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int position,idr;
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playdisplay);

        Intent i=getIntent();
        position=i.getIntExtra("position",0);
        play=findViewById(R.id.pause);
        next=findViewById(R.id.next);
        previous=findViewById(R.id.previous);
        songmar=findViewById(R.id.songnamemar);
        songmar.setSelected(true);
        songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        if(mediaPlayer!=null)
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
        mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Musicplay.this,uri);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        mediaPlayer.start();
        play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        Thread thread=new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                int max=mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                int currentposition=0;
                while (currentposition<max)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    currentposition=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    seekBar.setProgress(currentposition);


                }



            }


        };
        thread.start();
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(Musicplay.this);
        play.setOnClickListener(Musicplay.this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(Musicplay.this);


        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                if(position<(Musiclist.songname.size()-1)){
                    position=position +1;
                }
                else
                {
                    position=0;
                }
                Intent intent=new Intent(Musicplay.this,Musicplay.class);
                intent.putExtra("position",position);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });




    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        idr=v.getId();

        Thread thread2=new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        switch (idr){
                            case R.id.pause:
                                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);

                                }
                                else {
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                }
                                break;
                            case R.id.next:
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                                if(position<(Musiclist.songname.size()-1)){
                                    position=position +1;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }
                                else {
                                    position=0;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }

                                break;
                            case R.id.previous:
                                mediaPlayer.stop();
                                mediaPlayer.release();
                                if(position>0){
                                    position=position-1;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }
                                else {
                                    position=Musiclist.songname.size()-1;
                                    Uri uri=Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
                                    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(Musicplay.this,uri);
                                    int a=0;
                                    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
                                    {
                                        a=a+1;
                                    }
                                    mediaPlayer.start();
                                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                                    songmar.setText(Musiclist.songname.get(position));
                                    songmar.setSelected(true);
                                }
                                break;
                        }


                    }
                });




            }
        };

        thread2.start();






    }
}
```

please do suggest best way instead of starting same activity how can I play next song. I have even tried to change song in Oncompletelistner also but it works only once and then it doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of starting the activity again with different list position, just change the data source of the `MediaPlayer` object in the listener and use `reset()` instead of `release()` as it's more efficient.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
            if(position<(Musiclist.songname.size()-1)){
                position=position +1;
            }
            else
            {
                position=0;
            }
            uri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(new File(Musiclist.songpath.get(position))));
            mp.setDataSource(this, uri);
            mp.prepare();
        }
    });

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();

    }
});
```

Comment: again the issue is same it changes the song once only and then it stops. it doesn't keep on changing songs after completion

Comment: I got where I was wrong, it was calling start method before reaching in prepared state

Comment: If that helped you, please mark the answer correct for the community

Comment: Sorry but you have started mediaPlayer in Oncompletelistner, so it always throws error because mp didn't reached in prepared state so what I did was, I set a onpreparedlistner  and here I called prepare method and their I called start method. so in many cases people will get error in this. so if you rectify then I will mark correct

Comment: sure, update the answer!